# Join two different lists in MYSQL sorted by date?

Tags: mysql

Hello community I am working with MySql database, I have two lists with different records, but I want them together one below the other, depending on the date origin as well as I show below:

**The 1st list:**

```
SELECT  p.ICODPRESTAMO, 
    p.NCAPITAL, 
    (p.NMONPRESTAMO - p.NCAPITAL) AS INTERES, 
    DATE_FORMAT(p.TSFECCREACION,'%d/%m/%Y') AS FECHA
FROM TABPRESTAMO p
WHERE  p.ICODPADPRESTAMO IS NOT NULL 
    AND p.ICODPERBENEFICIARIA = 2
    AND p.SICODESTADO = 1;
```

SQL Return:

```
ICODPRESTAMO    NCAPITAL    INTERES FECHA
2   2000.00 200.00  01/02/2014
3   1650.00 247.50  04/06/2014
4   6000.00 900.00  09/06/2014
5   60.00   0.00    22/07/2014
6   600.00  48.00   06/01/2014
7   1500.00 112.50  28/03/2014
8   1600.00 64.00   24/06/2014
9   525.00  0.00    13/09/2014
18  582.00  0.00    03/10/2015
```

**The 2nd list:**

```
SELECT  a.ICODAMORTIZACION,
          a.NABOMONTO,
          DATE_FORMAT(a.TSFECCREACION,'%d/%m/%Y') AS FECHA
FROM TABAMORTIZACION a
WHERE  a.ICODPRESTAMO = 1
    AND a.SICODESTADO = 1;
```

SQL Return:

```
ICODAMORTIZACION    NABOMONTO   FECHA
1   200.00  16/03/2014
2   200.00  23/03/2014
3   200.00  30/03/2014
4   200.00  13/04/2014
5   200.00  20/04/2014
6   150.00  27/04/2014
7   150.00  04/05/2014
8   200.00  10/05/2014
9   200.00  17/05/2014
10  150.00  24/05/2014
11  232.00  15/09/2014
```

My goal is to unite the registration of each other, depending on the **FECHA**

As the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsH5F.jpg

Develop my procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE reporte4(cod_prestamo INT, cod_per_beneficiaria INT)
BEGIN

    -- Declaración de variables
    DECLARE ID_PRESTAMO INT;
    DECLARE CAPITAL DECIMAL(8,2);
    DECLARE PRESTAMO DECIMAL(8,2);
    DECLARE FECHA VARCHAR(10);

    -- Definición de la consulta
    DECLARE prestamo_beneficiario CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  p.ICODPRESTAMO, 
        p.NCAPITAL, 
        (p.NMONPRESTAMO - p.NCAPITAL) AS INTERES, 
        DATE_FORMAT(p.TSFECCREACION,'%d/%m/%Y') AS FECHA
    FROM TABPRESTAMO p
    WHERE  p.ICODPADPRESTAMO IS NOT NULL 
         AND p.ICODPERBENEFICIARIA = 2
         AND p.SICODESTADO = 1;

    -- Declaración de un manejador de error tipo NOT FOUND
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @hecho = TRUE;

    -- Abrimos el cursor
    OPEN prestamo_beneficiario;

    -- Comenzamos nuestro bucle de lectura
    loop1: LOOP

    -- Obtenemos la primera fila en la variables correspondientes
    FETCH prestamo_beneficiario INTO ID_PRESTAMO, CAPITAL, PRESTAMO, FECHA;

    -- Si el cursor se quedó sin elementos,
    -- entonces nos salimos del bucle
    IF @hecho THEN
    LEAVE loop1;
    END IF;

    -- Guardamos el acumulado de ventas y el código
    -- si el vendedor actual tiene mejores resultados
    -- SET FECHA_EVA = FECHA_EVA + FECHA;

    -- SELECT FECHA_EVA;

    END LOOP loop1;

    -- Cerramos el cursor
    CLOSE prestamo_beneficiario;

   SELECT prestamo_beneficiario;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I hope you can advise me how I should handle this case.

Comment: show your desired results also in your post based on 1st 2 results.

Comment: why did you tagged in php??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then use ASC order

```
SELECT
    `column_id` AS `id`,
    `column_name` AS `name`,
    `column_date` AS `date`
FROM `table_name`

UNION
SELECT
    `column_id` AS `id`,
    `column_name` AS `name`,
    `column_date` AS `date`
FROM `second_table_name`

ORDER BY `date` ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL use UNION method

for example

```
SELECT
    `column_id` AS `id`,
    `column_name` AS `name`,
    `column_date` AS `date`
FROM `table_name`

UNION
SELECT
    `column_id` AS `id`,
    `column_name` AS `name`,
    `column_date` AS `date`
FROM `second_table_name`

ORDER BY `date`;
```

Comment: That will not work properly when he has the same date in both SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the question a little unclear, but i think what you want is a FULL JOIN.

Basically, you need to do:

```
select * from
(
  select 1
) a
FULL JOIN
(
  select 2
) b
on a.date = b.date
```

where select 1 and select 2 are what you already posted.

But, since MySQL doesn't support FULL JOIN, you'll need to emulate it, the way to do it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)